# Linux install Client's SSL "ca-cert" in local?

Tags: https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have 2 Linux Servers (with LAMP):

1. Web Server with SSL (https://www.example.com)
2. Admin Server (needs to connect to Web Server, via https)

When i connect from Admin Server (to Web Server) via `curl` command. It is refusing. Then when i use curl with `--caeert` option, its going through. Like this:

```
# curl --cacert CAchain.crt -I https://www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
..
```

I'm getting `200 OK` only because of `--cacert CAchain.crt`.

Then obviously i need the pure/basic `curl` command without defining the `--cacert`, to be working. Like:

```
# curl -I https://www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
..
```

So that my Admin Application will *for sure* be able to connect to it (via https).

- But now, when i connect to `https://www.example.com` from Admin Server (via its Application), it is bouncing back. Not able to reach, with SSL.

How do i make my Linux (RHEL) to install the client's `CA-CERT` inside, in order automatically AVOID defining the cert file. So that any communications to "https://www.example.com" via CURL or Web Browser (from Admin), can just then successfully go through. (Is it something like, we make "SSH without Keys" logic? But how, please?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the CA cert to somewhere that `curl` can use it - it looks like you're just keeping it in your local directory (which isn't where `curl` looks for it - typically in some `/etc/pki/ssl/ca-bundle.crt`-type location).  There's a handful of ways to do this.  I don't have much experience doing it in RHEL (or CentOS), but have done it for Debian.

[This ServerFault Post](https://serverfault.com/questions/559571/install-a-root-certificate-in-centos-6) might help.

Likewise, [This Post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3711) might help you install/import the CA cert properly.

Comment: So that way can help "only" to curl? Actually my Server needs to connect that remote "https://" via the Web Application (not really from CURL). So what i really need is the Server-wide solution, regardless of what i connect via curl, or via Apache, or lynx or wtv. Will your approach apply to this, please. (Sorry for a bit confusions)

Comment: The answer is still the same - you need to import the CA cert into your Admin Server's Trust Chain, but the procedure may be a little different.  Check out RedHat's documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Certificate_System/8.1/html/Admin_Guide/Managing_the_Certificate_Database.html#Installing_Certificates_Using_certutil).

Comment: this solution works. But how is this approach called please? In other words, what are we doing here? Is it "Installing a root certificate"? =)

Comment: You got it - "installing a root certificate".  =)